# units of measure in fortran

Tags: fortran, units-of-measurement, fortran90

Is there a library defining a datatype and services to deal with quantities associated to a unit of measure in fortran ?

Answer (score 2):

There is the [PHYSUNITS](http://rime.aos.wisc.edu/gpetty/physunits.html) F90 module, which might do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Do mean something like [UDUNITS](http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/udunits/udunits-1/index.html)?  I find it really useful for time calculations, but most other conversions are just simple multiplication/addition combinations.  These are usually too easy to code manually to warrant the extra library dependency of UDUNITS.  Note that the more recent version, UDUNITS-2, does not yet have a Fortran interface.